# C++ declaring multiple classes in one header

Tags: c++, templates, header

I got an assignment where I am supposed to create a Linked list by using CRTP. I got some starting code/suggestion on how to define the classes in their respective header files. I have omitted some code below:

*Link.h*

```
#include <iosfwd>

template<class T>
class List;

template<class T>
class Link {
    Link* next;

    friend class List<T>;

public:
    Link();

    virtual ~Link() = default;
  //etc...
```

*List.h*

```
#include "Link.h"


template<class T>
class List : public Link<T> {
public:
    List();

    T* First();

    T* Last();
    //Etc...
```

This code compiles without any errors. Now my question is about the two first lines in Link.h, `template<class T> class List;`. I experimented a little bit and realized that Link.h won't compile without that class definition beacuse of the `friend class List<T>`  statement. But why can't I just write `#include "List.h"` and remove the inheritance inside List.h and just use that definition from the start? I have tried this of course and get the error

```
"error: 'List' is not a class template
     friend class List<T>;"
```

it would look like this:

*Link.h*

```
#include <iosfwd>
#include "List.h"


template<class T>
class Link {
    Link* next;

    friend class List<T>;

public:
    Link();

    virtual ~Link() = default;
```

*List.h*

```
#include "Link.h"


template<class T>
class List {
public:
    List();

    T* First();
```

Comment: Because of circular dependencies. They both include each other.

Comment: There is no CRTP here, just regular inheritance.

Comment: Why do you think that #include "List.h" would be preferable to template<class T> class List; even if you could do it? the include introduces the entire definition of list, (and any other contents of the file). A forward declaration just says "this is the name of a template/class", so that declaring it to be a friend doesn't look like an error to the compiler - and that's all that link.h required.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use a unique template in one file only or in files that build upon each other sequentially, not equally. In your case, you should probably move all of your files to one. Your .h files seem to mirror each other, so your compiler would have go back and forth between your references, but they do so in order. Choose the order of precedence.